# How does gcc make use of __builtin_<target>_func functions during compilation

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-construction, arm64

When compiling gcc for a aarch64 target, I see several __builtin_aarch64_##func## functions in the include/arm_neon.h file in the build directory.

For example,

```
__extension__ extern __inline float64_t
__attribute__ ((__always_inline__, __gnu_inline__, __artificial__))
vmulxd_f64 (float64_t __a, float64_t __b)
{
  return __builtin_aarch64_fmulxdf (__a, __b);
}
```

Where is the definition of __builtin_aarch64_fmulxdf() ? I cannot figure out how these builtins connect to the target specific md files.

Does the above mean the only way to generate this instruction is via an explicit call to this GCC extension ?

Comment: Found a related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930588/how-gcc-handles-built-in-function. Looks like those functions in arm_neon.h are NEON intrinsics. When building with GCC, the compiler will transform the __builtin_## calls, and will later spit out the machine instructions.

Answer (score 1):

These `__builtin_aarch64_*` functions are AArch64-specific GCC builtins. They are primarily used to implement the intrinsics in `arm_neon.h`.

GCC defines them internally in its code, not in some header file. They are not documented anywhere as they can be changed from release to release and users should not be relying on their behaviour.

The Advanced SIMD intrinsics in `arm_neon.h` are documented and defined in ACLE (https://developer.arm.com/technologies/neon/intrinsics for example) so you should be using those.

The target-specific builtins themselves are just an implementation detail in this context.